# Array overwrite issues in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets

I'm coding a google sheets extension. Basically, the script looks at a table like this:
"A" | "B" | "C" | "E~F"

For every string split by the "~" in column four, I need to create two arrrays so that the last column is E or F, but the remaining values are identical, like so:
[["A","B","C","E"],["A","B","C","F"]]
Now, theoretically this should be easy: I split the last column and loop over that. However, when I append my array, it overwrites the second value, leaving me with:
[["A","B","C","F"],["A","B","C","F"]].
Please note that column E will have an indeterminate number of elements in the future.
I appreciate any help!

```js
    var rangeArr=[["BF-A", "true", 'A kind reminder to make a weather report if you are on duty today', 'Something','2.0', 'Humphrey Bogart~James Dean'], ['BF-B', 'true', 'Kindly report on the condition of the BF now', 'Something else', '4.0', 'Humphrey Bogart~James Dean'], ['R-A6', 'true','A kind reminder to report on the reservoir level', 'Something completely different', '1.0', 'Angela Merkel']];
      var newArr=[[]];

      var count=0;
      for(i in rangeArr){
        var str=rangeArr[i][5];
        var places=str.split("~");
        var otherThings=rangeArr[i];
        otherThings.pop()
        for (a in places){
         otherThings[5]=places[a]
         var nextThing=otherThings
         newArr[count]=nextThing;
         count=count+1;
          
          }
        }
    alert(newArr)
```

Comment: Will there ever be more than two elements split from column E?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier, unfortunately the number of elements in column E is indeterminate and will become quite large.

Comment: I think the issue is that `newArr[count]` is actually being populated with a *reference* to `otherThings`, which is being updated with each iteration. A solution is to use `var nextThing = otherThings.slice()`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround. I do not understand entirely why the previous code does not work, and it probably reflects my lacking understanding of JS arrays. I simply created an array from the elements of two different arrays instead of appending an element to the original array.

```js
var rangeArr=[["BF-A", "true", 'A kind reminder to make a weather report if you are on duty today', 'Something','2.0', 'Humphrey Bogart~James Dean'], ['BF-B', 'true', 'Kindly report on the condition of the BF now', 'Something else', '4.0', 'Humphrey Bogart~James Dean'], ['R-A6', 'true','A kind reminder to report on the reservoir level', 'Something completely different', '1.0', 'Angela Merkel']];
  var newArr=[[]];

  var count=0;
  for(i=0; i<rangeArr.length; i++){
    var str=rangeArr[i][5];
    var places=str.split("~");
    var otherThings=rangeArr[i]; 
    otherThings.pop()
    for (a=0; a<places.length; a++){
      newArr[newArr.length]=[otherThings[1],otherThings[2],otherThings[3],otherThings[4],places[a]]
      count=count+1;
        
      }
  }
```